# Azure Websites: "Home" on C or D drive?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a new a new Azure Website (Code deployment) and noticed via the Kudu site, that the the files are now on `C:\` instead of `D:\`, e.g. this is from the Kudu site:

- Site folder: `C:\home`
- Temp folder: `C:\local\Temp\`

A week ago I thought that all my stuff was located on `D:\home` etc.

I asked this, because we deploy a WebJob via the Zip-Deployment option and need to set an absolute path to our config file, which is now on the "wrong" drive.

Also the [Kudu-documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) uses `D:` for all values.

Has this changed recently? It's not a major problem, but I want to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the Kudu console takes you to C:\home, D:\home is still accessible and points to the same place but I recommend you to always use the environment variable %HOME% and avoid using absolute paths.

For example, if you plan to use Windows Containers on App Service in the feature, the %HOME% env var also points to C:\home

Additionally, if you use App Service on Azure Stack for example, the %HOME% env var will also point to C:\home

Comment: Not 100% clear when Azure decides to use C or d, but the suggestion to use %Home% is good enough for me :)

Comment: hi @Joaquín Vano may i know how to change kudu console path to c:\home to d:\home, is there any specific page or tutorial i can get or it depends on the location?

Comment: @anirudhtalluri You can't, that's by-design because when you use Azure Websites / Azure App Service you're ceding low-level sysadmin tasks, including things like mounted volume drive-letters, to MS/Azure. If you want to be able to configure the OS then use a VM, not AppServices. You can't have it both ways.